# Getting an issue while installing mysql@5.6 in mac os

Tags: mysql

Im facing issue while installing brew install mysql@5.6
mac os: Monterey and version 12.5.1
issue :  Error: mysql@5.6 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!
please anyone have idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: Why are you using an old version of MySQL that is past its end of life? The simplest resolution is to use a support version, which is 5.7 or 8.0.